General result for $F(x,y,\ldots,y^{(n)})G(x,y,\ldots,y^{(m)})=0$
What are some general results for differential equations of the form $F(x,y,\ldots,y^{(n)})G(x,y,\ldots,y^{(m)})=0$?
The question is a sequel to my question here: A determinant leading to differential equations
Thank you very much in advance for your time.
